# Subfolder .htaccess redirecting to root folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here's my root folders .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Here's my subfolder .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/Admin/index.php [NE,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Admin/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/Admin/index.php [NE,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /stores/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/Stores/ [NE,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /categories/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/Categories/ [NE,R,L]

# working with client side
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?qstr=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^coupons/(.*)$ index.php?qstr=coupons/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?qstr=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

My problem is, when I try to access

```
http://domain.net/coupon-website/admin
```

I'm redirected to

```
https://www.domain.net/Admin/index.php
```

instead of

```
https://www.domain.net/coupon-website/Admin/index.php
```

What did I miss? Why am I redirected to root folder instead of coupon-website subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, I finally found a solution.
Here's now my new subfolder .htaccess and is now working as expected.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/coupon-website/Admin/index.php [NE,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Admin/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/coupon-website/Admin/index.php [NE,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /stores/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/coupon-website/Stores/ [NE,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /categories/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/coupon-website/Categories/ [NE,R,L]

# working with client side
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?qstr=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^coupons/(.*)$ index.php?qstr=coupons/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?qstr=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```